# C# Microsoft Test Unit with custom folder

Tags: c#, unit-testing, build

i'd like to ask some thing about VS2010 Test project. i have a class library project with a custom folder that contain configuration files. then i have a test project that will be used to test the class library. the problem is the configuration folder is not created on the test result folder everytime i build/run the test. how to make the folder and files created when i build/run the test?

thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do MSTest deployment items only work when present in the project test settings file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3738819/do-mstest-deployment-items-only-work-when-present-in-the-project-test-settings-f)

Answer (score 1):

You should use *DeploymentItems* to reference external content your tests depend on.

Here's a similar SO post with a step-by-step guide on how to do it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4604124/1373170