# MSTest DeploymentItem doesn't copy files to output dir

Tags: mstest, deploymentitem

nice day!

I have following project structure:

```
Solution
-My.Project
-My.Project.Test
--Resources
---mytest.file
```

In my test file following method:

```
[TestMethod]

[DeploymentItem("My.Project.Test\\Resources\\mytest.file", @"Resources")]

TestMethod()

{

....

string path = "Resources\\mytest.file"; ....

}
```

In according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182475%28v=vs.100%29.aspx I want use **only** DeployItemAttribute without "Deployment Items property".

But when I debugged it method, I catch "File not found exception".

What can I do?

PS: also posted this question in http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vststest/thread/474d51ee-7ab9-4311-b7b0-b21266eb01d5

Best regards!

Comment: Open the `TestResults` and check the file's path that MSTest tried to deplyed. But, I think that the problem is on your output directory. Use `"Resources"` instead of `@"Resources"`.

Comment: @Schaliasos, this file isn't contain in `TestResults` directory.

Comment: No, I mean to [view the TestResults](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404662.aspx) for the failed test to see the error. You can see the full path of the file you try to deploy and check that it is correct.

Comment: @Schaliasos, yes, yes it is there nothing :(

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check the properties of the file to deploy (*mytest.file*).

"Copy to Output Directory" should be set to "Copy Always" (it is set to "Do not copy" by default).

Comment: Check this post, it is the best troubleshooting description related to DeploymenItem I've seen: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3738819/do-mstest-deployment-items-only-work-when-present-in-the-project-test-settings-f?rq=1

Comment: Thanks for the useful link! It helps me. I understand that led me astray: ugly documentation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182475%28v=vs.100%29.aspx for example.

Comment: Yes, this worked for me.  For anyone else reading, make sure it's "Copy Always" and not "Copy if Newer", as the latter also doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 4):

Heads up that the path in [DeploymentItem("path")] is case sensitive.

For example: [DeploymentItem("MyTest.file")] is different than [DeploymentItem("mytest.file")] and will cause your deployment item to not be copied over to the TestResults Out folder.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, marking my "App.config" file as "copy always" fixed it for me.