# Class level DeploymentItem and DataSource

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, vs-unit-testing-framework

In my `TestClass` I have 6 test methods and for each test method I am using the same `DeploymentItem` and `DataSource`. Defining each time with each `TestMethod` is creating lots of redundancy in my code. Is it possible some how to define both of them one time for the complete `TestClass`?
I tried in `ClassInitialize` Attribute but could no achieve the the goal. Following is my `DataSource` and `DeploymentItem` detail:

```
[DataSource("CurrencyInfoList_DataSource")]
DeploymentItem("CoreUnitTests\\CurrencyUnitTests\\CurrencyTestData.xlsx")]
```

Answer (score 3):

Using the `DeploymentItem` attribute on the `ClassInitialize` method does not work. But instead, you can put it directly on your test class like so:

```
[TestClass()]
[DeploymentItem("MyFileToDeploy.txt")]
public class MyUnitTestClass
{
...
}
```

I'm not sure about `DataSource`, if that works as well. But probably it does.

Answer (score 1):

Simply enable deplyoment in your test settings and add the files you need to the settings, instead of adding them to each of the test methods.

See more details of how to achieve that here
[Do MSTest deployment items only work when present in the project test settings file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3738819/do-mstest-deployment-items-only-work-when-present-in-the-project-test-settings-f)

Comment: Thanks but in my case when I click on "Edit Test Settings" it is coming disabled (No Test Setting Available).. any idea?

Comment: create a test settings file and double click it